# Python Pytest skip rest /part of code in the function with @skip decorator

Tags: pytest

Is Pytest allows to skip not a whole test (function) but a part of code inside the function?

What I want (usage example):

```
def test_fill(my_dict: dict):
    assert all(v is None for v is my_dict.values()):
    my_dict.fill()
    # Temporary check for "foo" values
    assert all(v is not None for v is my_dict.values()):
    # Should skip the code below 
    pytest.mark.skip(reason='Need values setup')
    # The real checks with exact values are here (skipped for now)
    assert my_dict['key_1'] = 1  # Part of future test
    assert my_dict['key_2'] = 10  # Part of future test
    assert my_dict['key_3'] = 100  # Part of future test
```

How `pytest.mark.skip` supposed to work:
It may raise exception and quietly catch it.
And I will see it in the final test results output like in case of regular skipping.

Surely I can easily comment it, place in `if` branch, or skip the whole test with `@pytest.mark.skip` decorator,
but this will be not reflected in the tests output and it's easily to forgot about this weak test.

Comment: See [pytest.skip](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=skip#pytest.skip).

Comment: @MrBeanBremen Can you please post a solution or usage example? How this link should answer on my question?

Comment: Well, what is your actual question? You are asking if you can skip a test from inside a test, and this can be done using `pytest.skip`. Have you tried it? Or didn't I understand your question?

Comment: @MrBeanBremen. It works, great! You can post your comment as answer, I will accept it.
P.S. Sorry, I missed that you posted link to ` pytest.skip` and I tried to use `pytest.MARK.skip`. I've never seen documentation for the `pytest.MARK.skip`, well, I though you suggested me `pytest.mark.skip` when I used the link :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skipping a test while inside a test makes sense, if the information needed to decide if to skip a test is only available inside the test. This can easily be done using [pytest.skip](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html?highlight=skip#pytest.skip):

```py
def test_something():
    if not some_condition():
        pytest.skip("Condition not fullfilled")
    # do the test
```

This will skip the test the same way a `pytest.mark.skipIf` decorator will do, e.g. mark the test as skipped in the output and display the given skip reason.

In most cases (e.g. when the skip condition can be defined outside of the test) the decorator version can be used. From the documentation:

> It is better to use the pytest.mark.skipif marker when possible to declare a test to be skipped under certain conditions like mismatching platforms or dependencies.

For the sake of completeness: in `unittest` this is also possible by using [TestCase.skipTest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.skipTest).